# How to initialize SetState() in alert Dialogue in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Please guide me to short out the error.

I have a Delete Button in my Scaffold body, when I press the Delete button, It shows an alert dialogue with a Delete Confirmation Button. Now I want if someone clicks on Delete Confirmation Button, The button should replace with CircularprogressIndicator until the confirmation from API. And if the Confirmation response is true then Furthur another Alert Dialogue should Open. I am getting everything is working fine except the isLoading function on Confirmation Button.

```
FlatButton(
    color: Colors.red,
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
    ),
    onPressed: () {
      _showMyDialog();
    },
    child: Text(
      'Delete',
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 21, color: Colors.white),
    ),
  ),
```

My Delete function

```
Future<Category> deleteCategory() async {
  final http.Response articleByCategory =
      await _categoryService.deleteCategory(this.widget.categoryId);
  if (articleByCategory.statusCode == 200) {
    print(articleByCategory.statusCode);
    _showDelete(); // I am getting print statement but not _showDelete function
  } else {
    print(articleByCategory.statusCode);
    // ignore: unrelated_type_equality_checks
  }
}
```

from the above method, I am able to print response code from above but can not show _showDelete function.

My first Alert Dialogue with Confirmation Button

```
!isLoading
      ? FlatButton(
          onPressed: () {
            deleteCategory();
            setState(() {
              isLoading = true;
            });
          },
          child: Text(
            'Yes! Delete',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
          ),
          shape: StadiumBorder(),
          color: Colors.pink,
          textColor: Colors.white,
        )
      : CircularProgressIndicator(),
```

first dialogue

```
Future<void> _showMyDialog() async {
    return showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false, // user must tap button!
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Center(
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                child: Container(
                  padding:
                      EdgeInsets.only(left: 55, top: 50, right: 55, bottom: 15),
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            offset: Offset(0, 10),
                            blurRadius: 10),
                      ]),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        'Are you sure,You want to delete this category',
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style:
                            TextStyle(fontSize: 22, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 15,
                      ),

                      Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                        children: [
                          !isLoading ? FlatButton(
                              onPressed: () async{
                                // setState(() {
                                //   isLoading = true;
                                // });
                                await deleteCategory();
                                setState(() {
                                isLoading = true;
                              });
                              },
                              child: Text(
                                'Yes! Delete',
                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                              ),
                            shape: StadiumBorder(),
                            color: Colors.pink,
                            textColor: Colors.white,
                          ):
                          CircularProgressIndicator(),
                          FlatButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                              },
                              child: Text(
                                'No',
                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                              ),
                            shape: StadiumBorder(),
                            color: Colors.pink,
                            textColor: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                left: 55,
                right: 55,
                child: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                  radius: 50,
                  child: ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50)),
                      child: Image.asset("assets/recipe.png")),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: are you having two problems? not able to show the circularprogres indicator and not able to opent the confirm delete dialog?

Comment: also put the entire code for "_showMyDialog()" and "_showDelete()" in order to help you wtih finding out what is going wrong.

Comment: Only not able to show the circular progress indicator.  Confirm dlete dialogue is open without progressindicator

Comment: @MeanMan I have edited my question with dialogue codes

Answer (score 0):

You should make a class based on `StatefulWidget` for alert dialog content, so that you can use `setState` function there and show progress indicator when tap on delete button. And use that class in the builder of `showDialog` function.

Comment: you should better to post your code after using `StatefulWidget`

Answer (score 0):

```
     onPressed: () {
        //this is an async function, you need to await                                
        deleteCategory();
        // set the loading state before async call
        setState(() {
                                isLoading = true;

                              });
```

change your above method to below

```
onPressed: () async{
                        // set the loading state before async call
                           setState(() {
                                isLoading = true;

                              });
                      //wait for the future to execute                               
                       await deleteCategory();
                       //once the future is executed, make the loading false/ or 
                       //open the new dialog, after closing the current one.
                       setState(() {
                                isLoading = false;

                              });
```

Update

```
 builder: (BuildContext context) {
// return a statefulwidget
        return Center(
```

to

```
 builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return MyDialogContent(
```

where

```
MyDialogContent extends StatefulWidget
//declare the isLoading as state variable inside this class
...
...
build(){
//whatever you were returning in builder method, ie the Center widget
return Center
}
```

Comment: I tried but the same issue. Confirm dialogue is displaying without prograssindiacator

Comment: you need to share the code for _showdialg too, and another point to tc is , the FlatButton should the child of statefule widget, the widget tree should be like
AlertDialog ---> StatefulWidget ---> flatButton

if you are missing the stateful widget in the tree, nothing will happen, I can help you only if you share the the entire code of opening pertaining alert dialog.

Comment: so you are returning a "Center" widget in the builder method, extract this widget to a stateful widget,
create a new stateful widget, "MyDialogContent",  declare the isLoading state variable inside it, the build method of the class  should return the existing Center widget.